# Hardware accelerated Flash Player?

Tags: flash, hardware-acceleration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

According to Adobe statements they gave up support for hardware acceleration in newest flash player for linux :( Is there any other dev/alpha/beta version of flash player which enables hardware acceleration in Ubuntu 11.10?

Comment: Jorge's edited question. It's about Ubuntu 11.10 and current version of Flash Player 11

Answer (score -1):

If you have nvidia card, install drivers and vdpau files and you will have h/w with flash.

Comment: What are `vdpau files`? And how to install them?

Comment: Check software center for vdpau, install them and only if you have nvidia card and have installed necessary drivers for them.

Comment: Of course i have binary drivers and vdpau installed... that's not the problem. Read questions more carefully