# How do I fix Flash issues?

Tags: firefox, flash, google-chrome, chromium

I am having problems with Adobe Flash in Ubuntu, what are my options?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As you have identified - the best solution is usually to [follow this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11/how-do-i-install-adobe-flash-player) to install flash.  It does work for the vast majority of users.

---

#### Flash-Aid was discontinued by it's author and is unknown if it will be back, the following are kept only for historical reasons.

---

As an alternative, one of the best tools I have found that allows you to configure Flash correctly during installation is the Flash-Aid addon - use the [author's site](http://www.webgapps.org/add-ons/flash-aid/download-firefox) or search on the Firefox addon-manager for *Flash-Aid*

This will remove any remnants of of Flash installation and install flash directly from the Adobe Website.  During the wizard installation you have a few configuration options that you can try to resolve flash-player issues.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Close & Restart Firefox / reboot for the change to take effect.

See also:

- [Why are Flash applications so sluggish/crashy?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/852/why-are-flash-applications-so-sluggish?rq=1)

Answer (score 15):

There are 2 options.

### Enable the HTML5 player

For Youtube this can be done by loggin in, going to http://www.youtube.com/html5 and enabling it there. You can also just add `&html5=True` behind each video URL.

- [There is a trick for the cases when there appears to be no HTML5 option available on YouTube](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/youtube/qdlz0-ogSfI/jCBZZyry2k0J): use the "embedded" variant.

  For example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3SacL219sic&html5=True appears to be not watchable in HTML5, but https://www.youtube.com/embed/3SacL219sic plays in HTML5!

Whether your browser and the version you are using will support the HTML5 playback of a video on a site that provides such an option (like YouTube or [VKontakte](http://vk.com)) will depend on the **codec** chosen by the site owners. For example, YouTube and VKontakte (a Facebook clone popuar in Russia) use different codecs for their HTML5 videos, which means that [in Ubuntu 12.04 HTML5 video playback at VK.com works in Chromium, but not in Firefox (and in future, these browsers might swap their roles)](https://askubuntu.com/q/189433/19753).

### Install the Flash Aid Firefox plugin

I don't know for sure if this will work for you as well, but it worked for me.
Install [Flash Aid](http://www.webgapps.org/add-ons/flash-aid/download-firefox), restart Firefox, and click the Flash button at the upper right corner of Firefox's window. Just follow the instructions in the wizard and you should be fine.

For some more detailed guide on installing Flash using Flash Aid, check out fossfreedom's answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/86260/18953

Comment: This is good advice but note that only videos on Youtube encoded as WEBM are playable in HTML5 currently!

Answer (score 5):

### For Firefox Flash, first try this:

when having issues after an automatic update.

```
$ sudo apt-get --reinstall install flashplugin-installer
```

This leaves one with Adobe Flash plugin version 11.2.???.??? in Firefox as Adobe no longer releases any higher flash versions for Linux.

For the moment, the 11.2 series of the Adobe Flash plugin for Linux is **still maintained and security updates will trickle in automatically.** However, one will miss out on innovations and power efficiency improvements.

### For adding the Google Chrome Pepper Flash plugin to Chromium:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository --yes ppa:skunk/pepper-flash
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install pepflashplugin-installer
$ echo '. /usr/lib/pepflashplugin-installer/pepflashplayer.sh' |sudo tee -a /etc/chromium-browser/default
```

The latest and greatest Adobe Flash version for Chrome (version 12.0 at the time of writing) is installed in Chromium.

This solution can also be scripted for easy installation on multiple machines:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo add-apt-repository --yes ppa:skunk/pepper-flash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pepflashplugin-installer
STRING='. /usr/lib/pepflashplugin-installer/pepflashplayer.sh'
FILE='/etc/chromium-browser/default'
if ! grep -qe "$STRING" $FILE
  then
    echo "$STRING" |sudo tee -a $FILE
fi
```

Unlike Firefox Flash, **Pepper Flash is not updated automatically** by the update manager; it requires a tedious manual process. Forgetting about this leaves one exposed to security threats.

Here is another `bash` script to render manually updating Pepper Flash just that little bit less cumbersome:

```
#!/bin/bash
VERSIONS=$(sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --status)

UPGRADE=$(echo "$VERSIONS" |grep -oE '[^ ]+$' |uniq |wc -l)
UPGRADE=$(($UPGRADE - 1))

if [ $UPGRADE -ne 0 ]
then
    sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --install
fi

echo "$VERSIONS"
```

### Check your Flash version

In general, this can be done [on Adobe's site.](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player.html)

### The full story

Here is [the full story](http://www.howtogeek.com/193876/using-firefox-on-linux-your-flash-player-is-old-and-outdated/) nicely written up.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing Flash by entering the following command in the Terminal (make sure to shut down all running Firefox windows first)

```
sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
```

Comment: I wouldn't have asked it if it had been as simple as that.

Comment: Well, it might be as easy as `sudo apt-get --reinstall install flashplugin-installer`. This did the trick for me on Xubuntu 12.04 LTS after an automatic update to Firefox 27.

Answer (score 2):

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit with an Nvidia GeForce 8400 GS.

I have been having the same issue ever since I corrected another Flash issue on my system related to Nvidia GPUs -- see [Flash video appears blue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117127/flash-video-appears-blue) on this forum.  Following the workaround posted at the previous link stopped the unwanted behavior of all Flash video being tinted blue, but ended up causing the Flash plugin to crash nearly every time I attempted to watch a video online.

The solution for me was to look back at /etc/adobe/mms.cfg and remove everything but one line, which should read:

```
OverrideGPUValidation=true
```

This idea and others are [discussed on ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1985689), and many other places.  Please try changing your mms.cfg (or creating it, if it does not already exist) and post back with your results.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

As for the HTML5 video playback option available at some sites:

First, not all sites provide HTML5 videos as an alternative to Flash (hopefully, there will be more).

And second, whether your browser and the version you are using will support the HTML5 playback of a video on a site that provides such an option (like YouTube or [VKontakte](http://vk.com)) will depend on the **codec** chosen by the site owners. For example, YouTube and VKontakte (a Facebook clone popuar in Russia) use different codecs for their HTML5 videos, which means that [in Ubuntu 12.04 HTML5 video playback at VK.com works in Chromium, but not in Firefox (and in future, these browsers might swap their roles)](https://askubuntu.com/q/189433/19753).

And third, some videos might appear to not have the HTML5 option on YouTube. (For example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3SacL219sic&html5=True.) But thanks to [the answer by Klementine](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/youtube/qdlz0-ogSfI/jCBZZyry2k0J), there is a trick useful for getting at HTML5 playback in these cases -- use the "emdedded" variant. (For my sample video: https://www.youtube.com/embed/3SacL219sic.) And it works!

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to go to http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/;

Then, select "APT for Ubuntu 10.04+".

A window should pop up prompting you to select a program to use the apt link: you need to direct it to `/usr/share/software-center/software-center`.

This file should be a Python script.

When it opens the Software Center, enable the source it tells you to.

Then, once it is done, hit the install button. You may need to restart Firefox for it to work, but that's how I did it, and it worked for me!

Comment: if you go to get.adobe.com/flashplayer then there's a selection from the dropdown that says "APT for Ubuntu 10.04+" At least it shows up for me.

Comment: Sorry. I am on 13.04. It shows only tar.gz. and .rpm files.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to Enable the Adobe Flash plugin in Opera by following the [instructions from this Russian post](http://linuxforpeople.livejournal.com/13226.html).

Let us begin installing Flash:

- Install PepperFlash via apt: `sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree`
- download & extract the Adobe Flash: https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/debug_downloads.html

  - get the "**Download the Flash Player Plugin content debugger (64-bit) - NPAPI**" version (note that if your running on 32-bit architecture, you need to select the 32-bit one)
- Extract: `tar xvf <archive_name>`
- Move the file `libpepflashplayer.so` to `/usr/lib/pepperflashplugin-nonfree/`
- Restart Opera. and you're done.

### I can now see them installed:

- checked on https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player.html

[image]

- and on `about://plugins`

[image]