# Flashplayer plugin does not connect to audio streams

Tags: sound

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

ALSA plug-in [np-viewer] is up and working.

Any idea?