# Poor quality video with graphics card GeForce 9500

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, video, 3d

Seeing bad quality video on internet.

I've installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my machine that is an AMD Athlon x2 5000+
4 gb ddr3 GeForce 9500 GT/PCI/SSE2

When I play some video on the internet, like YouTube, in 480 or higher, in full-screen mode the quality is very low. I get the same problem with the effects on my desktop

I tried all the drivers shown in the list of available drivers but none of them solves my issue; the one that works best is the current one.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have tried the nvidia-current driver and your graphics have improved slightly, probably means that you are correctly using the NVIDIA drivers rather than the opensource nouveau drivers.

If your graphics issues are restricted to Youtube and other internet videos, probably yours is a Adobe Flash issue rather than a graphics driver issue.

Can I suggest you use the Flash-Aid add-on as described in my answer below to reinstall Flash.

---

Linked Question:

- [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/no-flash-on-firefox-8)

Comment: the problem extended, or at least i have noticed that, to other graphic sections of my display...like effects (compiz), when i change from a window to another the image gives me some imperfections!

Comment: I'm wondering... is this a compiz issue?  Can you logout and login to the unity-2D session.  Do you still have the graphical issues?