# Why do I have poor video performance in browsers with a ATI HD3650 GPU?

Tags: ati, flash, performance, browser, html5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

I'm experiencing poor video performance on Youtube, both in Firefox and in Opera - Flash and HTML5 (all of the combinations). HTML5 is actually worse. Videos on Vimeos such as http://vimeo.com/channels/hd#33971928 play super smoothly sometimes, choppy other times. Usually smoothly for first 5 seconds, choppy later, sometimes recover.

```
Lenovo Thinkpad T500 <br>
Ubuntu 11.10 x64 <br>
AMD 3650 graphics, Catalyst 11.10 <br>
Unity 3D, Unity 2D <br>
Flash 11,2,202,160 (IIRC the 64 bit one installed through Flash-Aid didn't make any difference)
```

It's frustrating as on Windows I haven't experienced this kind of issue on a decade old hardware.

It seems it got solved by a single change - switching from ATI HD3650 to integrated Intel graphics card. Now I can play smoothly even 1080p YT videos. But the performance is poor if switched back.

Comment: Please add your edit as an answer and accept it when you can (you will need to wait for a couple of days).

Comment: I'm not sure whether you got the edit no 2 in which I insist the question is not being marked as answered for, to me, obvious reason - the improvement was due to switching to another graphics card (ATI to Intel). Configuration has changed. For the previous configuration the problem is still valid.

Comment: I'm suffering from the same problem. I use a NVidea grafic card with the proprietary drivers installed. I tested also all Flash versions with the help of Flash Aid but nothing helped. Since HTML5 on Youtube has the same problems, I suppose it's not connected to Flash anyway. I've found somewhere the optino "Sync to VBlank" for your grafic card driver might help, but it doesn't.

Comment: One additional note on troubleshooting similar problems: Make sure you start your troubleshooting with checking behavior with your browser "Use hardware acceleration" option ON/OFF. Just an idea. Nothing specific.