# Flash stops working in Firefox

Tags: 11.10, firefox, flash, 32-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

I got a weird issue this morning: after an update, my firefox flash plugin stopped working. For any flash object I try to run, it appears a weird black page with a slider on the bottom (like a video player) but nothing happens.

Obviously, any of the flash videos (or even games) tried were working perfectly under Google Chrome.

I tried to remove and reinstall *adobe-flashplugin* from USC, but nothing changed.

I had Oneiric 32bit with some testing repo like *ricotz-testing* ppa (even if I don't know if this matters).