# Repeated warning about updating my Flash player

Tags: 10.04, firefox, flash

I have installed new firefox, however flash doesn't work.
When I visit for example YouTube.com instead of vids I see info: please update Your flash player.
I am trying to use apturl package for Ubuntu but it gets me a message that: this file cannot be opened because "apt" is not recognized by any program.

How to solve this issue?

Thanks and regards,
Misery

PS.: ubuntu 10.04 LTS x64
     flashplugin-nonfree or any other flash package don't solve the problem

Below I wrote what finally helped :]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know the problem. Have you tried yet if this solution works for you?
[How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/no-flash-on-firefox-8)

Flash Aid did the trick here, I guess new versions of Firefox don't like old versions of Ubuntu :p

Comment: It doesn't work. As before I still get a message that flash should be updated

Comment: Does it show up in the **Plugins** screen of Firefox? If yes, is it greyed out? If also yes, what note is beneath it?

Comment: It helped finally. Description is below :)

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found out the reason why it didn't work.

First of all one has to download 64 bit version of Firefox which is not on the download website (so it has to be found somehow). Installed it as usual:

```
tar xjf firefox..bla..bla..x64
sudo mv firefox /opt
sudo ln -s /opt/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox
```

and run firefox by writing in terminal:

```
/opt/firefox/firefox
```

than I have installed flash aid add-on and it did the rest: installed stable flash plugin.

Answer (score 0):

flash plugin also produced issues on my 10.04 x86_64 system.The soultion might be to purge all installed flash verions and install from this ppa:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner
```

After that update your package information and install the following package:

```
adobe-flashplugin
```

If you understand german you can also read the background on this german website (where I got it from):
[ubuntusers.de](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/adobe_flash)

Comment: No command 'deb' found, did you mean:...

Comment: I guess I'll handle without flash. Anyways it's just linux :]
It's normal taht nomal stuff doesn't work and ultra specific stuff works normally :p

Comment: You re unfair now... with windows you have similar problems - the only problem with linux is, that hardware and software vendors dont care for linux users. And if you regard that, the support Linux contributers offer without support form those big companies, then it is great!

Comment: I know, that problems with drivers under linux are the fault of hardware producers. :] But chill out, I am using Ubuntu at work and I am very satisfied. However I use only LTS versions and half year after its release. I haven't told that Linux developers did anything wrong, I just said that it is normal that all the unusual stuff like scientific tools and libs etc work like gold under linux, but there are some problems with usual stuff. But anyways... we have VirtualBox to run windows if needed, and finally it solves the problem at last, when all workarounds fail. Regards.

Comment: Maybe just dont give up that fast. deb is not a command,rather those lines are ppa-information which you should just add tpo your ppa list, e.g. using software center, sth like "Add software package source" and then install the package I mentioned.Also the package "flashplugin-installer" could do the trick.It is a little tricky because flash isnt open source...