# Late sound in flash

Tags: flash, adobe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

I am learning linux and now have ubuntu 11.10, 10.10 on my PC. The problem is on both.
The problem occured with playing flash via web.
Flash does not lag, but the sound is going late for some seconds. I tried to google that problem, but yet I can't find any good manual.
I tried to delete/reinstall flashplugin-nonfree. Nothing.
I tried all browsers from software centre. Nothing again.
Please, help me. I don't want to get rid of ubuntu only because of that problem.
Thanks.
*PS. Sorry for my english, I am not from e-speaking country.*

Comment: Have you similar problem windows?
What about connection speed?
Any problems while playing music from your computer?

Comment: No, I have quite good configuration and in windows there are no such problem. Also there are not such problem running Slax Linux

Comment: And no problems while playing local music.