# Flash Player Crashes with Firefox/ Chrome/ Chromium

Tags: flash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

I searched , but i found only old problems. The solutions of them did not helped me at all. I tried to install manualy flash from adobe, also adobe-flashplugin and flashplugin-installer etc in repos, but with no luck.

FP crash in video sites like youtube and vbox7(dot)com (it's bulgarian alternative of youtube), but no crashing in flash pics and some games like 5strike(dot)com.
Here is a code when I run chrome/firefox/chromium in terminal and try to run flash video.

didko@Acer:~$ firefox
WARNING: pipe error (68): Едностранно прекъсване на връзката от отсрещната страна: file /build/buildd/firefox-10.0.2+build1/build-tree/mozilla/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 419

didko@Acer:~$ chromium-browser 
[20165:20175:21125651132:ERROR:web_data_service.cc(625)] Cannot initialize the web database: 2

(exe:20306): Gdk-WARNING **: XID collision, trouble ahead

(exe:20306): Gdk-WARNING **: XID collision, trouble ahead

Edit: I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 with gnome-shell