# Flash chat problem , under the ubuntu 1204?

Tags: 12.04, flash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

just this time every time i hit space on the chat while playing flash game on web browsers like games  from facebook or G+ ,  the whole screen game-play is going down , and i cant see the game sometimes it crash while chatting at poker room or other games rooms , anyone have clue how to fix it ?

Comment: Are you trying to say there's a performance issue or that the screen scrolls down? It's hard to understand your question

Comment: Did you try this in another browser?

Comment: all browser jakob
yeah something like that , when you go to play some flash game and pressing spaces .. or while playing game so all flash screen going down .

Answer (score 0):

Try this bookmarklet on the page. Even if it stops the space bar in a text area, so you can't type a space (you can use Shift+Space), it should work in flash embeds too.

```
javascript:function dSpace(e){if((e.keyCode==32)&&(!e.shiftKey)){e.preventDefault();}}window.addEventListener('keydown',dSpace,true);void 0;
```

To remove that event listener, use:

```
javascript:window.removeEventListener('keydown',dSpace,true);void 0;
```

Comment: not help man i trying to add those java script instructions and still have the same problem . :s