# Broken packages : after attempting to install flash

Tags: package-management, flash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

```
installArchives() failed: perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of adobe-flashplugin:i386:
 firefox (12.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) breaks adobe-flashplugin (<= 11.1.102.63-0precise1) and is installed.
  Version of adobe-flashplugin:i386 to be configured is 10.0.32.18-1.
dpkg: error processing adobe-flashplugin:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of adobe-flash-properties-gtk:i386:
 adobe-flash-properties-gtk:i386 depends on adobe-flashplugin (= 11.2.202.233-0precise1); however:
  Version of adobe-flashplugin:i386 on system is 10.0.32.18-1.
dpkg: error processing adobe-flash-properties-gtk:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 adobe-flashplugin:i386
 adobe-flash-properties-gtk:i386
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of adobe-flash-properties-gtk:i386:
 adobe-flash-properties-gtk:i386 depends on adobe-flashplugin (= 11.2.202.233-0precise1); however:
  Version of adobe-flashplugin:i386 on system is 10.0.32.18-1.
dpkg: error processing adobe-flash-properties-gtk:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of adobe-flashplugin:i386:
 firefox (12.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) breaks adobe-flashplugin (<= 11.1.102.63-0precise1) and is installed.
  Version of adobe-flashplugin:i386 to be configured is 10.0.32.18-1.
dpkg: error processing adobe-flashplugin:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any record of an `adobe-flashplugin` with the version `10.0.32.18-1` ever having been published in the `partner` repository.

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/adobe-flashplugin/+changelog

Where are you installing it from? Can you run:

```
$ apt-cache policy adobe-flashplugin:i386
```

Please?