# I cant update my flash player - Sonicwall issue

Tags: installation, firefox, flash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

In my university webcentre I administer 20+ PCs having ubuntu 12.04 installed and updated  up to date.

The campus network has sonic wall, for everyone who need to access internet need to enter common password, and user name.

Sonic wall is logged in through Firefox, after logging in a tiny Firefox window appears, which needs to be minimized to connect to the Internet.

While updating flash, it asks to close Firefox, then only flash player starts to install, but installation closes as when i close Firefox, the internet stops.

Answer (score 0):

Yuo can manually download the flash from [here](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/) and install it.
But remember to first uninstall the already installed version