# Can't watch Youtube Flash  videos in Opera Browser on Ubuntu

Tags: flash, browser, opera

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

i can't watch Youtube videos in my opera browser on Ubuntu 10.04, the page is fully loaded but the space where the player is to be is blank (black) and i have flash player installed but it still won't work... any advices on the matter?

Comment: does it works on any other browser? if not, try this : sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras

Answer (score 0):

Remove or disable Video-Downloading Extensions , No-Script , or Flash Block like extensions and give it a try. If that does not help try removing or disabling all extra added extensions.

Also checkout http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1953796.

Also Adobe has announced it plans to discontinue the stand-alone Flash Player for Linux.

Comment: actually there isn't any extensions, so i was wondering which one i need to get?

Comment: Do you have any graphics driver installed , check if it is properly installed .Try Removing flash completely , do a new installation of Flash.