# Sound is glitching

Tags: 12.04, sound, flash, pulseaudio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

Hi' I'm having the issue with audio on my Ubuntu.
The problem is, when I play some music in any player and I move to another part of track, sound becomes kinda crackling/chopping or something for a while, and them it continues as usual. These artifact is really a problem because it sounds too loud even louder than music.
I've tried to edit /etc/pulse/default.pa and /etc/pulse/daemon.conf files as written here https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pulseaudio#Glitches.2C_skips_or_crackling but that doesn't help.

Also, I have trouble with flash player. When I start playing video, the sound appears with delay about 500 ms. When I stop playing, it sounds for additional ~500 ms.

Motherboard P8P67 with built-in audio; Ubuntu 12.04, pulseadio.
Anyone help?