# Window and menu freezes after watching flash videos

Tags: nvidia, flash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

I've got a problem with a freezing desktop. After or while watching flash videos in firefox or chrome, all menus and windows are freezing temporarily, only Keyboard is working. I can open new terminals and work there, but I can't close or move any window. I'm using the recommended proprietary NVIDIA driver.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The latest flash-player is buggy in conjunction with hardware acceleration. You may try to disable it by typing in a shell:

sudo mkdir /etc/adobe

(maybe your shell will conplain that this directory already exists. You can safely ignore that)

Next you should enter in the shell:

sudo echo “EnableLinuxHWVideoDecode=0″ > /etc/adobe/mms.cfg

You need finaly to restart your brower.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, but it didn't work for me.