# Flash stopped working in firefox after I installed VLC

Tags: firefox, flash, vlc, adobe, media

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

Flash Aid does not help, nor does uninstalling/reinstalling VLC, Flash, and Firefox
Tried disabling other plugins on firefox that may have something to do with flash media also to no avail.

Comment: How did you install VLC?

Comment: via terminal, synaptic wasn't working at the time, for some reason, the command I used was sudo apt-get install vlc vlc-plugin-pulse mozilla-plugin-vlc

Answer (score 0):

Try and disable some of the plugins in Firefox. Maybe one of the media plugins is the culprit.

Comment: nope, that didn't work either.

Comment: I'd suggest you try removing mozilla-plugin-vlc. The playing of flash might now be going through vlc (I don't know why that wouldn't work, but this might help narrow down the problem).

Comment: what should I type to do that? when I try sudo apt-get purge mozilla-plugin-vlc it says it is not installed.

Comment: In firefox, addons menu, plugins tab

Comment: Actually that's what I already tried.