# Adobe Flash not working in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, flash, adobe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

I cannot get Adobe Flash working in either Firefox or Chrome. I have tried the Flash-Aid plug in for Firefox but it has not made any difference. As far as I can see, Flash installs without error and Firefox thinks it can run Flash but (for example) YouTube just shows a blank square where the movie should be me. Chrome reports "missing plugin".

about:plugins in Firefox reports:

Shockwave Flash

```
File: libflashplayer.so
Version: 
Shockwave Flash 11.2 r202
```

MIME Type   Description     Suffixes
application/x-shockwave-flash   Shockwave Flash     swf
application/futuresplash    FutureSplash Player     spl