# Flash videos will not play

Tags: flash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

Flash videos doesn't work after upgrading.  Flash is installed.  Tried to uninstall and reinstall but seems that it doesn't help

Comment: Which browser/media player are you using? I think that it's not Flash's fault.

Comment: Are you trying to view downloaded videos, or are you playing them from a website?

Comment: Do you also have the `gnash` plugin instaled, by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

If this is in Firefox, try to install [Flash-Aid](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flash-aid/).