# Español/English - Trouble downloading / Problema descargando adobe-flashplugin_11.2.202.236

Tags: flash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

Me sale esto al actualizar el sistema (apt-get update upgrade), probé usando el comando sudo dpkg --configure -a como me indica, bajando flash desde la pagina oficial y en todos los intentos me sale mismo, simplemente no pasa de ahí.

I just keep getting freeze ups, I mean the computer has about 6 hrs downloading flashplugin. every time I try to update or use dpkg to get flash.

[image]

Comment: did you try using apt-get install or Ubuntu Software Center?

Comment: Both software center and apturl options just give me the same result, is it dpkg missing something? btw thanks~

Comment: Do You have such a problem only with Flash? Does other software give the same problems?

Comment: Even after deleting the lock, Only flash gives me the problem.

Comment: try `sudo apt-get purge flashplugin` where flashplugin is that what You have installed. And try to install it again via apturl. If that doesn't help please try [Flash::Aid](https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/flash-aid/)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion You should go to [Adobe get Flash www](http://get.adobe.com/pl/flashplayer/otherversions/) and install it using apturl (choose Linux OS and apturl). Installation should proceed automatically. (Here I assumed x64 Ubuntu).

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Please run(in a terminal) `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, let it finish, and then try installing again.

(I don't have accent keys) Por favor, ejecute `sudo dpkg --configure -a` en Terminal(Buscelo en Unity) y repite la instalacion de Flash.

Comment: Sorry, my limited Spanish is pathetic...