# Flash removal and installation issue

Tags: package-management, flash, adobe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

I'm having this issue trying to uninstall and/or upgrade the Adobe flash player plug-in.  Here's what I've ran through the terminal:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.0.0-13-generic libgladeui-1-11
  linux-headers-3.0.0-19-generic linux-headers-3.0.0-13 linux-headers-3.0.0-19
  erlang-base
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  adobe-flashplugin
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 10.2 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 375840 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing adobe-flashplugin ...
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for iceape-flashplugin.
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for iceape-flashplugin.
dpkg: error processing adobe-flashplugin (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
 postinst called with argument `abort-remove'
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 adobe-flashplugin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Please advise if you can. Let me know if there is any other info you need.

Comment: Does `dpkg --remove adobe-flashplugin` help you in some way?

Comment: Was your browser running when you installed flash?