# can't open youtube or vimeo

Tags: networking, flash, lubuntu, youtube

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

I can't open Youtube.com on computer with lubuntu and mint. I see that my flash works properly on other sites. Problem is in for example on youtube (yming.com loading without endless) and vimeo. I tried to use firefox and chromium.
I thought that it would be problem with dns (I have dns from DHCP - opendns) so I changed to google dns but it didn't help to solve problem.
When I use text browser - Links these site are opening well in text mode. I think that the problem is with flash or java. On other computer with windows connected to the same network these sites are being opened without problem.

I am on the point that I don't know what to do next, because I tried to install and uninstall flash several times. I tried Flash-Aid as well.

Comment: Have you tried updating your flash?

Comment: It's not Java, as YouTube doesn't use that. Apart from that, I don't know.

Comment: @zpletan probably it's true, but if I turn off java script in browsers page are loading really fast, but they are incomplete. I read a lot of materials and I thought that it is problem with dns or dnsmasq, but I don't know and I observed that the Interent works really slow, when I use browsers. ... endless Looking up s.ytimg.com on my browser scary me, the same is when site has plugin: google -analitics or facebook, or plus.google it sproblem to connect to these sites. I tried dev version of flash and stable one. The last thing what I tried, it was install flash by using Flash-Acid. Stable ver

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is mainly to access Youtube and not about resolving the Flash problem, you can try [HTML5 for Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/html5/).

In case of HTML5, YouTube doesn't need Flash and hopefully, your problem should be solved.

Recent versions of any modern browser should support HTML5.