# Is there any (lightspark.so update.alternative) as adobe flash "automatically"?

Tags: 12.04, flash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

Hi I have been trying to solve lightspark settings, and I could not find anything to repair. I was wondering if there is a command that makes you do a update-alternative, or works for firefox. And also let me know which video sites it supports, or is it to youtube?. Well who knows anything, thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what the problem/question is, but I think you want to use flash with your Firefox browser.

Try this

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

and restart your firefox.

Hope this helps ....

Comment: Hola, yo tengo instalado ubuntu-restricted-extras, pero quiero instalar lightspark,(how to, configure?, some "update-alternative" comand to run?). Y si alguien sabe que sitios son soportados por el programa lightspark, ¿todos?. Quiero un sustituto de Adobe flash. Gracias

Comment: ALL IS NOT LOST Chromium-browser does already come with built-in Flash support, ¡WE STILL HAVE ACCESS TO ALL VIDEO FORMATS OF THE WEB!  ^_^

Comment: Adobe has been working closely with Google to develop a single, modern API for hosting plug-ins within the browser. The PPAPI, code-named “Pepper”, aims to provide a layer between the plug-in and browser that abstracts away differences between browser and operating system implementations. You can find more information on the Pepper API at http://code.google.com/p/ppapi/.