# Flash does not work under different user account.

Tags: flash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

Flash works under my first created user account. about:plugins shows File: /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libflashplayer.so, which is fine. Works with Firefox and Chromium.

When I log out and login into another or new user account, about:plugins does not show the Flash plugin. Neither in Firefox nor Chromium.

I tried flashplugin-nonfree, flashplugin-installer and flash-aid, installed under different user accounts. It always works only under my first created user account.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple of possibilities (not even sure they're the most likely, as not as familiar as I used to be with browser plugins):

- wondering if the other users do not have access permissions to the directories the plugins are installed in - maybe the group access/world readable permissions?
- maybe (variant on above's core reason) the plugins have been installed in a user-owned directory rather than a common one (in /usr/lib//plugins, usually, or nearly that)
- other user's browser settings configured to look in the wrong place for plugins?

Try to figure out where the plugins are and see if the other users can see them too (and read the files).