# Chromium on ubuntu 12.04 - YouTube doesnt work

Tags: 12.04, flash, chromium

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

For about last two weeks, probably after flash update I cant watch youtube. Everytime I try to watch something my chromium is crashing. I dont know what to do. I can watch everything on firefox and it works very well.

Chromium 18.0.1025.168 (Build 134367 Linux) Ubuntu 12.04
Flash version - 11,2,202,236 
What do? Thanks in advance

Comment: Open up a new tab in Chromium, and type **about:plugins**. Do you see the Flash plugin? If so, is it enabled?

Comment: Yes, it is :<<signs>

Comment: I have exactly the same version in Chromium and flash version 11,2,202,238. I can watch all types of videos. Maybe you should upgrade it or re-install it (e.g. synaptic package manager - mark for re-installation).

Answer (score 0):

Where are you getting your Chromium build? Mine out of the Ubuntu repos is 18.0.1025.151 (Developer Build 130497 Linux) Ubuntu 12.04.

This might be the problem. You could try uninstalling this Chromium and installing the one from Ubuntu's repos.

Comment: Here you go: my sources list. Is something wrong with this? http://pastebin.com/BxYuCB85

Comment: Well you have several third party repos there. Your Chromium build is probably coming from one of them which makes it harder to compare. This is one reason why I do not like to add a lot of third party repos.

Comment: Try this, open a terminal and put in 'apt-cache show chromium-browser'. Paste the output here. If you can figure out where it is coming from, uninstall it, open up your sources.list and comment out the repo. Then install Chromium again. It should install from Ubuntu. Then we can see if it is their build or if the issue is something else.

Comment: third party repos? What is this?

Comment: so which reposhould I comment? http://pastebin.com/0zmmFDA2

Comment: Try this 'apt-cache policy chromium-browser' and post the output.  How did you install Chromium?

Comment: apt-get install chromium-browser. http://pastebin.com/Y8wWM3PW

Comment: Your version is coming from the chromium daily build, but I don't see the repo listed on what you posted. Look for something like http://ppa.launchpad.net/chromium-daily/stable/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 and comment it out. If it is not on there then try removing Chromium and installing it again. It should pull it from the Ubuntu server then.

Comment: nothing works. Any ideas?