# Why is my `/usr/lib64` directory empty, even after installing adobe flash 64bit

Tags: 64-bit, filesystem, flash, 32-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

Well, I installed Adobe Flash Player 64 bit today and I noticed, it asked me to place something in `/usr/lib64` but after installation, it's empty !! Everything is in `lib`  not in `lib64`, Which I don't understand because I have a 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Can someone help me ? I'm a bit new to Ubuntu and I would like to get this "lib64" and "lib" confusion settled because if I'm running 32-bit programs without knowing it, I'd love to fix that so maybe everything will run faster. I have 4 gigs of RAM.

Comment: There  is  **/lib64** , have a look in this Directory.