# how to make browser video go fullscreen

Tags: 12.04, video, flash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

I have been trying to watch videos in my browser on fullscreen.

For example : http://www.nhs.uk/Video/Pages/Glueearanimation.aspx?searchtype=Search&searchterm=glue+ear&offset=1&

but also youtube videos have trouble, though with the latter I can usually get it to 'stick' fullscreen if I keep trying enough times.

What happens is that the video goes fullscreen for just a moment, then goes back to its previous size/position embedded in the browser.

Using the above URL, using either the fullscreen button, or the 'go fullscreen' menu option, has the same errant effect.

I'm using Firefox 13.01 and Flash version 11,2,202,236, on Ubuntu 12.04.