# Flash Player plug-in could not be added to firefox or opera plug-ins!

Tags: flash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

I use ubuntu 11.10 and firefox and opera browsers.

Every time I install flash player plug-in (the original of adobe or the installer mode), no plug-in adds to firefox or opera. Why?!

I tried Gnash and lightspark (?) too. But the problem was existing yet.

What should I do?

Comment: Try removing it completely and then do a fresh install . If not try [flash-aid](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/flash-aid/).

Answer (score 0):

Visit http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/ 
 Then Select Version as APT for Ubuntu 11.04+ 
 Them Click Download Button, Terminal will be opend....
Please protect your inernet connection from disconnecting.

Comment: Sorry to say but there is no APT version , its a source(.tar.gz) file which needs to be compiled .

Comment: apt:adobe-flashplugin?channel=$distro-partner                    paste this above line in to browser address bar then click enter

Comment: Then you need to place this URL http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/ instead  the above in answer. I will edit it :)

Comment: You can also add that in above answer as Alternative option :)