# Firefox flash player fullscreen mouse doesn't disapear 12.04?

Tags: firefox, flash, fullscreen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

In Ubuntu 12.04, Firefox's flash-player, full screen mode.

When I want to watch a video that is not YouTube, the mouse pointer should disappear, just like it does Windows, but in Ubuntu 12.04 it does not, how do I make it disappear?

I can't hide it in the screen corners because:

I can see it if I put it in the top corners.

In bottom corners, the controls won't disappear.

So, how to make the mouse pointer disappear in flash player's full screen mode, on a site that is not YouTube? Again, in YouTube works, the mouse pointer disappears, just like it should.

Comment: I have a solution, but still it is not what I'm searching for; It's an app that makes your mouse cursor disappear no matter what after x seconds of idleness; It's called: Unclutter