# Chrome flash problems on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, flash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

I have problems with flash on Chrome but on Firefox everything is ok.

This is on Chrome:

[image]

This is on Firefox:

[image]

Can you help me to fix this. This is not only on that site, it's on all flash sites, including You Tube.