# Problem with the Logitec OrbiCam webcam: how to troubleshoot it?

Tags: 12.04, kernel, flash, webcam, skype

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

My webcam is working/not working rather curiously under ubuntu 12.04, and I'd like some help in troubleshooting it.

It's a Logitech Orbicam, integrated within my Acer Aspire 5633WLMi laptop.
With lsusb it is identified as:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:0896 Logitech, Inc. OrbiCam
```

Luckily, it works correctly when doing a Google Hangout from Chrome.

But the strange thing is that the capture through Adobe Flash (e.g. omegle, chatroulette) does not work: the cam is not detected.

Skype for linux does not detect it. Cheese crashes on startup (see the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cheese/+bug/1026587)).

What could I do to troubleshoot and fix the problem?

There must be a way to make it work under skype/cheese and the other websites. I remember using it some years ago (older versions of ubuntu and skype) and it worked perfectly.

**UPDATE**:

If I run skype with either

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l2convert.so skype
```

I get the following in /var/kern.log

```
Aug 15 14:41:57 maggie kernel: [  653.296753] usb 1-4: USB disconnect, device number 7
Aug 15 14:41:57 maggie kernel: [  653.328056] gspca_vc032x: reg_w err -19
Aug 15 14:41:59 maggie kernel: [  655.140094] usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci_hcd
Aug 15 14:41:59 maggie kernel: [  655.315878] gspca_main: vc032x-2.14.0 probing 046d:0896
```