# Why is Flash video trying to play across both displays?

Tags: flash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

This didn't always happen but Flash tries to play video across both displays. Any ideas how to fix this?

[image: Flash is playing video across both screens]

Comment: I've seen this happen with specific ads that try to determine screen geometry (Jeep ads on hulu).  It's not the whole of flash in my case, it's one screwy ad.

Comment: I found a workaround in the meantime. Right click video and click "pop out" then full screen that.