# Why can't I play HD flash videos in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, video, flash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

I have a Asus U32U-RX128V laptop, it is great. I installed Ubuntu 12.04 and nearly everything works
I had many difficulties to install the video card drivers

```
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 6320 Graphics
OpenGL version string: 4.2.11762 Compatibility Profile Context

libva: VA-API version 0.32.0
libva: User requested driver 'xvba'
libva: Trying to open /usr/lib/va/drivers/xvba_drv_video.so
libva: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 0.32 (libva 1.0.15)
vainfo: Driver version: Splitted-Desktop Systems XvBA backend for VA-API - 0.7.8
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Advanced            : VAEntrypointVLD
```

My laptopt is able to play a full HD movie (1920*1080) on a TV but is not able to play videos in firefox

I tried HTML5 rather than Flash, its WORSE !
I tried Greasmonkey and Viewtube, videos don't play at all or lag a lot.

What option do I have ? Windows allows me to play HD videos in Firefox with no lag, so Ubuntu should be able to do the same...

Thanks !

Comment: Are you talking about movies in flash?

Comment: Can you play a 1080p video in totem?

Comment: What's the problem; does the video not load, or is it extremely laggy, or what?

Comment: Yes I am talking about flash but also HTML5 and the plugin player used by Viewtube.

Totem can't play a 1080p while VLC can.

Sometimes the video does not load, sometimes it loads but its always very laggy