# which type of Flash for ubuntu 12.04 in Firefox

Tags: flash, version

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

When I visit the Flash page to download it for the first time on Ubuntu 12.04 it's got a dropdown box asking whether I want to install 'YUM for Linux', or 'tar.gz for other Linux' or '.rpm for other linux'.

I would like someone to tell me which it should be (in any) and possibly,why.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You should install Flash from Ubuntu Software Centre.

It is best to install Flash as part of 'ubuntu restricted extras' as this package also includes many other proprietary codecs that you will need.

Just click the shopping bag on the launcher to open Software Centre, then search for ubuntu restricted extras, and click install (where it says remove on the image below).

[image: ubuntu restricted extras]

Comment: I can see I should have typed the above in here. Oh well.....

Answer (score 1):

Using firefox for running flash is useless. Adobe has not supported Flash for Linux again. But Adobe still provides security updates for latest version Flash for Linux, 11.2.

You can use Chrome for running flash contents. Google still continue to privode the next version of compatible flash player, called Pepper. This works well even though not originally coming from Adobe.

Sorry for my english, wish it can help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of installing flash manually, search for "flashplugin-installer" in the software center. This package will download and install flash for you.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! I now have Flash (so as to be fair I shan't say which way I installed it!) but it's now up and running fine. I really like this Software Centre. It's something Microsoft is certainly lacking. It takes all the pain out of choosing which version etc.