# Streaming video does not play smoothly. CPU struggling with simple tasks

Tags: video, performance, windows-xp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

I have a desktop made in 2004.  It has a 3.0 GHz processor with 2 GB DDR2 533 Mhz dual channel and a Radeon 4670 PCI-E card w/ 1 GB DDR3 RAM.  It has a WD Caviar blk 640 GB HD w/ 32 MB cache.

I have it dual-booted w/ Windows XP SP3  and Ubuntu 12.04 with XFCE and XMBC packages also installed.  While Ubuntu is running, processor is sometimes at about 94% even while running only Firefox or Software Center.

While running Firefox, images sometimes load slowly and video steaming stutters and audio is out of sync.  Also thumbnails in my picture files load a lot slower than on XP.

Xfce is a bit smoother with video but still struggles with full screen.  I should mention that my Internet speed is about 3mbps, however XP somehow is faster.

I have always heard that Linux runs well on older systems but I am wondering how I can improve performance.

Comment: Full screen flash video on Linux has always been painful, and it's not going to get better, since Adobe has discontinued development.