# No audio in flash player, both chromium and firefox

Tags: 12.04, sound, flash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

I use Kubuntu 12.04 LTS, and in Firefox and Chromium the Adobe Flash plugin will not play audio.

Google Chrome's plugin works, but I don't really like Chrome/Chromium, I installed Chromium only to test it.

I tried various versions of the plugin and both adoble-flashplayer and flashplugin-installer. Tried the "delete .pulse and create some files" fix and didn't worked too. Tried every single fixd I found in web and nope, didn't work.