# The buttons and seek bar disappeared from Youtube videos - what can I do to remedy this problem?

Tags: flash, youtube

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

The buttons (pause, stop, seek, etc) have suddenly disappeared from Youtube videos.

Does anyone have any ideas that could guide to defining the problem more accurately and then find a solution?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Have you installed some new custom style for your browser?