# Is there any way to synchronize flash audio and video?

Tags: 12.04, flash, audio-sync

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

I've tried to search, but nothing works.
My Flash audio is always out of sync. It's in all browsers.
I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 32bit and alsa without pulseaudio.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try the following in Chrome (if that's what you're using):

Enter `chrome://plugins/` in address bar, click on `details`, if there are more than two Shockwave Flash entries listed under `Flash`, disable one of them and see if there's any improvement. If not, go back reactivate the entry and disable the other one. See if it's better now.