# Flash video streaming choppy for Chrome, alright for Firefox

Tags: video, flash, google-chrome, streaming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.1, Chrome 21 and Firefox 15. Flash player 11.2 has been installed, and I've just started using Ubuntu... yesterday. And I'm using a **Lenovo T61**.

The problem is that it doesn't matter if it's youtube or vimeo or some other flash player, it streams fine on chrome but every 30 seconds or so, there is a pause in video playback (with audio continuing) before it catches up, skipping quite a few seconds of video.

It works perfectly fine in Firefox, and I've tried disabling PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so
in Chrome but it doesn't seem to affect the performance.

Anyone know how to work around this? It's more a problem of convenience because I don't like the idea of having to switch between Chrome and Firefox just to watch videos.

Answer (score 0):

If you downloaded Chrome directly from Google, that might be your problem.  If that's the case, try downloading "Chromium" directly from The Ubuntu Software Center.