# Chrome flash problems

Tags: 12.04, flash, google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

I guess this happened after the most recent update of the system.
If I open chrome://plugins I see the following:

> Flash (2 files) - Version: 11.2 r202 Shockwave Flash 11.2 r202
>
> Name: Shockwave Flash Description:    Shockwave Flash 11.3 r31
>   Version:  11.3.31.232
>   Location: /opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so
>   Type: PPAPI (out-of-process)       Enable
>
> Name: Shockwave Flash Version:    11.2 r202
>   Location: /usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libflashplayer.so Type:  NPAPI

If both are enabled(or only the first one), video and sound are too fast, if the first one is disabled, video is too slow but sound is normal.

How do I solve this?