# Can't see YouTube videos in either Firefox or Chromium

Tags: 10.04, flash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

Dont' know why or if it is related, after upgrading Ubuntu 10.04 kernel ( I guess from 2.6.32-38 to -42) I can's see youtube videos. I checked the flash plug-ins installed and I have: (1) flashplugin-installer, (2) flashplugin-nonfree and (3) flashplugin-nonfree-extrasound. I haven't reinstalled the browsers yet. Here's the code of the plugins installed:

```
williepabon@raquel-desktop:~$ sudo lsb_release -a; uname -a; dpkg -l | egrep 'flash|gnash|swf|spark'
[sudo] password for williepabon:
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS
Release:    10.04
Codename:   lucid
Linux raquel-desktop 2.6.32-42-generic #95-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 25 15:57:54 UTC 2012 i686 GNU/Linux
ii flashplugin-installer 11.2.202.238ubuntu0.10.04.1 Adobe Flash Player plugin installer
ii flashplugin-nonfree 11.2.202.238ubuntu0.10.04.1 Adobe Flash Player plugin installer (transit
ii flashplugin-nonfree-extrasound 0.0.svn2431-3 Adobe Flash Player platform support library
```

Any ideas to solve this issue? Thanks.

Clarification: 
Problem is with the Flash plugin. Chromium says "missing plugin", Firefox shows a blank screen where the video was suppose to appear. Vimeo messages "Shockwave Flash has crashed"

Comment: Does other than Youtube Adobe Flash content on the internet work? And what *exactly* are you experiencing? Does your browser complain about not having a compatible plugin installed to view the content for example? Please be more specific than "can't see".

Comment: As a workaround you can activate [YouTube html5](http://www.youtube.com/html5).

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to Flash Player whose version is too old (11.2). I get it with Chromium on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: I just visited youtube using firefox and flash version 11.2r202 and it went to the default html player. Using google chrome and pepper flash 11.3.31.232 it defaults to the flash player.Possibly the firefox version they are using doesn't support the html5 player. He could download the latest google chrome and use the built in pepper flash. or alternatively use chromium with pepper flash. maybe that could be expanded to your answer.

Comment: My Flash Player plugin is also version 11.2. What perplexes me is that I have another machine with 10.04 LTS that has the same plugin version (different kernel 3.0.0.25) with same apps (chromium, Mozilla and Chrome) and flash works OK on all browsers. So, I don't know what's going on. Any help is appreciated. Kernel on this machine is 3.0.0.26 now.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer, for anyone with a similar problem. Here it is:

Since this is an old computer, you may have the wrong CPU for version 11 of Flash. Use
`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep sse2`
and if nothing is printed, that's your problem.

See the following for more information on what to do (parts 4, 5, and 6): http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linuxquestions-org-member-success-stories-23/getting-flash-plug-in-to-work-with-older-cpus-4175420481/