# Flash maximizes to wrong monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, flash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

Is it possible to control which monitor applications (Flash esp.) maximize to? If it matters I'm using my CPU's internal video chip (HD4000).