# Flash animations doesn't work

Tags: flash, plugins, youtube, animations, html5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

I have a following problem:

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed on my Athlon 1800+ + 1 GB RAM + Nvidia Geforce4 MMX 440 (pretty old configuration) and everything works just fine except Flash Player in my Web browser (tried Firefox and Chromium). Instead of movie/animation, I get blank space.

I updated my system via update manager,

checked the plugins (everything OK),

installed and updated flash player one more time,

installed Ubuntu restricted extras,

tried Firefox's Flash Aid,

even tried Youtube Html 5 (still the same result)...

Please, help me! I enjoy working with Linux and Ubuntu is the first that works for me well (after Open Suse and Fedora) but I have no idea what is wrong now...