# Video playing problem of Epiphany browser on Ubuntu 12

Tags: flash, browser, epiphany

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

I am using ubuntu 12 and Epiphany as browser but it does not play flash contents. I installed flash player from software center but still does not work. What else can I do to solve he problem? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Use a browser that supports flash like firefox, chromium, ect.

Known bug for Epiphany (Web),  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/epiphany-browser/+bug/904505

Comment: but your suggested ones are slow compared to that light browser. F-Do you have any suggestion for lightweight browser like epiphany.