# Flash Video Intermittent Browser Freeze

Tags: graphics, video, flash, browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

I have had this issue for a while, and have searched for solutions. It may be associated with my graphics card (since I also have other issues) but I am not quite sure.

I can play Flash videos just fine in both firefox and chrome, both generally load quickly. However, very intermittently, either or both browsers will have all graphics freeze within the browser window. It looks like only within the browser window the graphics card fails to refresh the image. This affects the video, scrolling, and tabs. To refresh, I have to switch apps or click on the desktop to remove focus from the browser, which then automagically refreshes. Somtimes this is permanent and I can keep using it, sometime it is temporary and as soon as I click on the browser again it freezes again.

Very important to this issue is that the elements in the browser, like tabs, links, and scrolling still function. Example: start youtube video, browser freezes, try to scroll down the page, nothing happens, click on desktop to remove focus from browser, window refreshes to the point the scrolling should have ended. i.e. scrolling does not *seem* to occur after refresh but during scrolling, and is only shown after browser loses focus.

Dell Precision T3400
Dual monitor setup
Ubuntu 12.04LTS with latest updates
Nvidia Quadro FX 570/PCIe/SSE2.

Any ideas?

Comment: This error is sometimes augmented by the entire screen freezing. Half the time I can recover this error by restarting unity, the other half of the time I have to logout and login again, or even do a hard reboot if I can't access the terminal. I am not sure if these issues are related, but they are both graphics issues. At times it actually seems that it is the flash videos in conjunction with compiz that freezes unity (when switching desktop spaces).