# Not being able to play Flash on Firefox & Ubuntu12.04

Tags: 12.04, firefox, flash, plugins

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

I've already installed Adobe flash player and Gnash flash player...one at a time of course
In both cases i've tried to play a flash video from youtube and....i've seen just a white rectangle instead of the video.
Also tried flashaid ...witch installed the standard adobe flash player...same results.
in both cases the plugin was active
Installed the ubuntu restricted extras...no result
Tried to install the above plugins with synaptic....no result

Am i missing something?...Am i doing something wrong?
Any pointers whould be apreciate
 Thank you

Comment: In software center, Did you mark Adobe Flash add-on when you installed ubuntu-restricted-extras package?