# Some flash videos (e.g., on IGN.com) won't play 12.04

Tags: 12.04, firefox, flash

Ubuntu 12.04, 32-bit, Firefox 17

For some reason I can play YouTube videos fine, but on websites like IGN.com the videos never load. Everything plays fine in Chrome, but the videos used to work in Firefox and for some reason they no longer do. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I just tried with 32-bit Firefox 17 but on Ubuntu 12.10 and videos worked on IGN.com. Do you have some ad blocker or NoScript or Ghostery type of extension active? Have you tried with extensions disabled? Sometimes, an update to extensions' blocking lists could cause problems for sites that previously loaded just fine.

Comment: did you install extras?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I fix Flash issues?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

Answer (score 1):

I have no problems with flash usually, but there was one particular elearning site that just didn't want to display it's content, whatever I tried. Ubuntu 12.10 and Firefox.

I installed agent switcher add-on from https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/ and switch to "Internet explorer 8" (in the Tools menu)  - problem solved, all flash content plays OK. This particular site was asking for IE, Firefox or Chrome browser, and Adobe Flash 10 or higher.